# Is LINQ similar to PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, linq, pdo

I've learned about ASP.NET and have some exercise with Linq, but now i'm prevering to PHP for Web Development. I just wanna know Is LINQ similar to PDO? and does PDO safe from PHP Injection or MYSQL Injection?

Comment: PDO is safe from SQL (it can connect to more than just mysql) injections **if** used correctly (parameterized queries). It does nothing to protect the rest of a PHP project.

Comment: Not a C# ASP.NET developer, but wrt PHP and PDO, no, simply using PDO does not make you safe against SQL injections. Prepared statement support in PDO will do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO is not the same as LINQ.

PDO offers native interface to SQL, while LINQ is a language by itself, that can be internally translated to SQL when appropriate.

LINQ can be roughly compared to query builders used by PHP frameworks.

PDO is immune to SQL injections if properly used (when whole SQL query is hard-coded in your script while all the data variables are bound through placeholders).